# What should I do when a question should be split?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

This [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15128/how-much-power-is-being-needed-by-aircraft-ife-and-cabin-lightning-systems-durin) in the second one in a week that I would have liked to split into two separate ones. IFE has very little to do with cabin lightening and it would perhaps see that the OP was just wondering about both and asked them together. It is not really productive for the site question database when looking for answers later. What should I do?

- I can't create a new question in his name.
- I don't want to go deleting half the stuff from that one.

---

Update: That quesiton was just updated by the OP but they might not always understand the purpose or idea, especially when they are new to the site.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best course of action is what you did, comment it. By commenting it gives OP chance to learn how this site work and adjust accordingly. Sometime they miss fine print in help center. That's where more experienced user come in. If no OP action is taken then it is up to people who answer it whether they want to answer both parts or just one.

So my conclusion is, comment it.